# PyMongo client close in class framework

Tags: python, mongodb, database-connection, pymongo

I have a Python class in which I create PyMongo MongoDB connections during init (see code below). I want to instantiate this class in another script and then ensure that all connections are closed at the end of the script. If I do so, then run `self.client.close()` as below and then check on open connections, I get back a return that looks as if there are still active connections. Am I overthinking this, and all connections are actually closed?

```
class BaseClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = MongoClient("url")
        self.cursor1 = self.client.get_database('db1').get_collection('col1')
        self.cursor2 = self.client.get_database('db2').get_collection('col2')

test = BaseClass()
test.client.close()
test.client.connections
```

```
Database(MongoClient(host=['url'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, retrywrites=True, w='majority', authsource='admin', replicaset='url', ssl=True), 'connections')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are overthinking it; there's no need to close connections, pymongo's connection pooling will take care of this for you.

If you are needing to create lots of these objects, it will be more efficient to create one MongoClient connection and then pass that as a parameter to each class.